# Mysqli update to string creates 0 instead

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I'm creating a php application for a non profit to manage donations and consolidate contribution receipts into one platform so that the accounting dept can more easily keep track of who donated and when. Here is a quick overview of what this should do:

- Pull down donation information from Platform 1
- Add that data to a mysql database on our server
- Using a separate file, pull the data out of our servers and search for each contributor in Platform 2
- If a person is found, add a contribution receipt for that user in Platform 2, and change their status to "Matched" in our DB.
- If there are no matches for the contributor in Platform 2, change their status to "Error" in our DB, and eventually add the error message "No matches".
- If there is more than one match for a contributor in Platform 2, change their status to "Error" and eventually add the error message "X amount of matches found"

The problem I'm having is that when I update a contributors status to "Matched" it works, when any other situation occurs (No matches, or multiple matches), The "status" column changes to a 0 instead of "Error", and no message is printed in the "Error" column. I can't seem to make it work!

Here is the code in question, with some sensitive info changed of course...

```
// Get People with Status Code "unMatched" from Valve2_0
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Contributions WHERE status='unMatched' AND type='Credit Card' ORDER BY epochDate LIMIT 10";
$results = $conn->query($sql);

if($results->num_rows > 0){ // If there are search results
    while($person = $results->fetch_assoc()){

      $r = $f1->searchPeople(array(//search attributes
          "searchFor"=>$person['name'], // Name
          "include"=>$person['phone'].','.$person['email'] // Phone Number Search for Phone Number
      ));
      date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Create Receipt Variables
        // Get subFund aka Trip Name
        $subFunds = $f1->getGivingSubFunds($fund['@id']);
        $sf = array_search( $person['tripName'], array_column($subFunds['subFunds']['subFund'], 'name'));
        $subFund = $subFunds['subFunds']['subFund'][$sf];


        // Create Received Date & Transmit Date
        $cd = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", $person['epochDate']/1000);
        $receivedDate = new DateTime($cd);
        $transmitDate = new DateTime();
// SINGLE MATCH
    if($r['results']['@totalRecords'] == 1){
        echo "Congrats! We found only 1 match for {$person['name']}.<br>";
        // Create foreach
        foreach($r['results']['person'] as $result){

    // Add Contribution to person
        $receipt = $f1->contributionReceiptModel;
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['accountReference']= $person['id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['amount'] = (float) $person['amount'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['fund']['@id'] = $fund['@id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['fund']['name'] = $fund['name'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['subFund']['@id'] = $subFund['@id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['household']['@id'] = (int) $result['@householdID'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['person']['@id'] = $result['@id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['contributionType']['@id'] = $type['@id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['contributionSubType']['@id'] = $subType['@id'];
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['receivedDate'] = $receivedDate->format(DATE_ATOM);
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['transmitDate'] = $transmitDate->format(DATE_ATOM);
        $receipt['contributionReceipt']['memo'] = "Contribution  id:{$person['id']} $nbsp; To: {$person['donatedTo']}";

        // Create variable to send the receipt
        $addContribution = $f1->createContributionReceipt($receipt);
        $conn->close();
        // If Contribution Receipt was Created
        $conn = new mysqli($DB_host, $DB_user, $DB_pass, $DB_name);
        if($addContribution){
        // Update our Database to reflect that the person was "MATCHED"
          $update = "UPDATE Contributions SET status='Matched' WHERE id='{$person['id']}'";
          $conn->query($update);
          $conn->close();
          unset($update);

        } else { // If Contribution Receipt was NOT created
          echo "Something went wrong adding {$person['name']}'s contribution!<br>";
          $update = "UPDATE Contributions SET status='Error' WHERE id='{$person['id']}'"; // Update our Database to reflect that the person was "MATCHED"
          $conn->query($update);
          $conn->close();
          unset($update);
        }} // End "If only one match" && End Foreach Loop
      } elseif($r['results']['@totalRecords'] > 1){ // If there is more than one match
      // Get All Results and Assign Variable to them
      // Assign Variable to "unMatched"
        $conn = new mysqli($DB_host, $DB_user, $DB_pass, $DB_name);
      echo "Multiple Results For: {$person['name']}<br>";
      $update = "UPDATE Contributions SET status='Mult' AND error='Multiple Matches Found!' WHERE id='{$person['id']}'"; // Update our Database to reflect that the person matched multiple entries
      $conn->query($update);
          $conn->close();
          unset($update);
    } else { // If there are NO results
      // Write code to say "No Results"
      $conn = new mysqli($DB_host, $DB_user, $DB_pass, $DB_name);
      echo "No Results for: {$person['name']}! <br>";
      $update = "UPDATE Contributions SET status='None' AND error='Contributor does may not exist!' WHERE id='{$person['id']}'"; // Update our Database to reflect that the person was not found!
      $conn->query($update);
          $conn->close();
          unset($update);
    }
  } // End WHILE Loop
} else {
  echo "There are no new unMatched Contributions right now, try again later!";
}

?>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! If I need to include any more information please let me know!

Comment: `UPDATE`'s `SET` clause is comma separated column=value sets.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external files, downloads or pictures. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: `AND` doesn't do what you think it does in your query.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you! I tried to paste my code in using the `code` syntax but I couldn't get it to look right with the commented sections of my PHP! I appreciate the fix!

Comment: What kind of column type is your "status" column? VARCHAR?